# Get the index of the highest value inside a numpy array for each row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array of 30 rows and 4 columns, for each row I need to get the index where the highest value is located.

So for an array like this

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],[7, 4, 5]])
```

I would like to get a list with the indices `2` for the first row and `0` for the second row.

I tried with the numpy function argmax as follows:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    results=[np.argmax(a)]
return (results)
```

but I just get the global maximum, does anyone know how to go around this?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html) method with `axis=1` in order to work on the rows.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],[7, 4, 5]])
>>> a.argmax(axis=1)
array([2, 0])
```

There is also the [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) module level function which works just the same.

```
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
array([2, 0])
```

Comment: Easy with your reputation to close this as a duplicate. You have a gold badge for python

Comment: Clearly a duplicate. Should close!